# if/else statement not triggering

Tags: java, android

I am trying to do 1 of 2 things. IF all of my EditText are input with some data where length>0 then it should progress to my math equations and put the data into EditText dispMinPmt. If there is a NULL value EditText field, it should do the Toast at the end. Currently, neither are occurring. There are also no errors to display.

Here is my .java:

```
@SuppressLint("ShowToast")
public void ButtonOnClick(View v)
{
    TextView dispMinPmt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dispMinPmt); 
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.calculate1:
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Check 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        EditText nickname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editNickname);
        if (nickname.getText().toString().length()>0)
        {
            String debtNickname = nickname.getText().toString();
            EditText origBal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editOrigBal);
            if (origBal.getText().toString().length()>0)
            {
                String myOrigBal = origBal.getText().toString();
                Double originalBalance = Double.parseDouble(myOrigBal);

                EditText myAPR = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editAPR);
                if (myAPR.getText().toString().length()>0)
                {
                    String myEditValue2 = myAPR.getText().toString();
                    Double apr = Double.parseDouble(myEditValue2);

                    EditText myOrigTerm = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editOrigTerm);
                    if (myOrigTerm.getText().toString().length()>0)
                    {
                        String myEditValue3 = myOrigTerm.getText().toString();
                        Double originalTerm = Double.parseDouble(myEditValue3);

                        double r = apr/1200;
                        double r1 = Math.pow(r+1,originalTerm);

                        Double minPmt = (double) ((r+(r/(r1-1))) * originalBalance);
                        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");      
                        minPmt = Double.valueOf(df.format(minPmt));

                        dispMinPmt.setText("" + String.valueOf(minPmt) + "Mo.");

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please complete all fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Here is my layout (.xml)

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".DebtInput" >

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textNickname"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Debt Nickname" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editNickname"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:text="Car Loan"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textOrigBal"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Original Balance" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editOrigBal"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:text="10000.00"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textAPR"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="APR (%)" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editAPR"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:text="0.00"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textOrigTerm"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Loan Term (Months)" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editOrigTerm"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:text="60"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textOutBal"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Outstanding Balance" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editOutBal"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:text="1000.00"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/calcButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/calculate1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Calculate" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textMinPmt"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Minimum Payment" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dispMinPmt"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textAddPmt"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Additional Payment" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editAddPmt"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:text="100.00"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/calcButton2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/calculate2"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Calculate" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow8"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textNewPmt"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="New Payment" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dispNewPmt"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/buttons"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Add" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/clear"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Clear" />

</TableRow>
```

Comment: First of all, they are edit texts to get data and not text views.

Comment: give the complete scenario.

Comment: Your Text fields may be null and causing a NullPointerException. Check your logs.

Comment: Anil Bhatiya - true, sorry for the mis-tyle

Veer - I provided you all of the details. i input data in to all of my editviews and it does not either calculate, or display the calculated data.  Also if I purposefully leave a edit blank, it does not do the toast.

Comment: Your toast will only run if `nickname.getText().toString().length()==0`, and nothing will happen if any other fields are left blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
android:onClick="ButtonOnClick" is missing from the XML
```

Comment: In the future, it would help if you explained what this does, and generally provided more information. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your IF statements is overly nested. This is a bad practice. Also, your else statement will only trigger if the 1st condition is not met. If any of the subsequent conditions are not met, nothing will happen.

I tool the liberty to tidy your code a bit:

```
public void ButtonOnClick(View v)
    {
        TextView dispMinPmt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dispMinPmt); 
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.calculate1:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Check 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            EditText nickname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editNickname);
            EditText origBal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editOrigBal);
            EditText myAPR = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editAPR);
            EditText myOrigTerm = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editOrigTerm);

            String nicknameStr = nickname.getText().toString();
            String origBalStr = origBal.getText().toString();
            String myAPRStr = myAPR.getText().toString();
            String myOrigTermStr = myOrigTerm.getText().toString();

            double origTermValue;
            boolean origTermIsParsable;

            try
            {
                origTermValue = Double.parseDouble(origBalStr);
                origTermIsParsable = true;
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException  e) 
            {
                origTermIsParsable = false;
            }

            if (nicknameStr.length() > 0 && origBalStr.length() > 0 && myAPRStr.length() > 0 && myOrigTermStr.length() > 0 && origTermIsParsable)
            {               
                Double originalTerm = origTermValue;

                double r = apr/1200;
                double r1 = Math.pow(r+1,originalTerm);

                Double minPmt = (double) ((r+(r/(r1-1))) * originalBalance);
                DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");      
                minPmt = Double.valueOf(df.format(minPmt));

                dispMinPmt.setText("" + String.valueOf(minPmt) + "Mo.");

            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please complete all fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            break;
        }
    }
```

Generally speaking, nesting so many IFs inside each other is something you should always try to avoid. In the event that you have two if's one inside the other, eliminate one of them, and combine the conditions with an "AND" statement.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I appreciate the advise. Obviously I am new to this and I have not seen that suggestion before. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are trying to compare a string using `>` and that won't work. You either need to make it into an `int`; or, you need to use the `equals` method to compare strings. Using the `equals` you won't be able to use greater-than or less-than though.

Comment: In that case let me ask you this.. how should i verify that the editview has data input in to it?

Comment: If all you are trying to do is verify that it has data you can do: `nickname.getText().toString() != null`.

Comment: Based on this I did the following:         EditText nickname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editNickname);
   String debtNickname = nickname.getText().toString();
   if (nickname.getText().toString() != null)
   {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "PING", 100);
   }                and the Toast did not activate while data was present.

Comment: where is that though? Are you sure you are even getting to that? Looking at your switch statement, I'm curious to know if you are even entering it.

Comment: I am activating my calculate button that has ID calculate1

Comment: Are you sure you are entering the statement though? Looking at your code, I get the feeling that you aren't even going into the case you expect.

Comment: You basically have a method called `onButtonClick` usually when you are clicking a button you have an `onClickListener` I don't see that. That leads me to believe that you aren't getting into the case you expect. The debugger is your friend :)

Comment: My intent is that when I click my first button "calculate1" that it begins the checks and calculating process -- the other buttons are set for expansion that I have not programmed in yet.

Comment: I get what your intent is. My point is that what you are intending to do and what is actually happening are 2 very different things. Set a breakpoint at the beginning of your code and step through it. You will see if you are working as you intend to.

Comment: I did find my error, I was able to keep the onButtonClick, but I neglected to add android:onClick="ButtonOnClick" to my XML

Answer (score 0):

Try adding **trim()**
It will remove all spaces included , like this

```
nickname.getText().toString().trim().length()>0
```

Also put this line in your onCreate Method

```
 TextView dispMinPmt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dispMinPmt);
```

Comment: I put a Toast directly after the nickname IF and included your's in my if with the trim() and it did not do the toast (or anything else)

Comment: Is your method getting called, ButtonOnClick(View v?

Comment: Updated answer, try this

Answer (score 0):

```
int value = 0;
value= Integer.parseInt(edittext.getText().toString());
```

and check if value>0 .

This is the case to check when your edit text data is integer value and not the string.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `StringUtils.isEmpty(nicknameStr)` method, rather than `nicknameStr.length > 0`.